# convert string with UTF-16 and UTF-8 text to UTF-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, utf-16

I read many posts on how to convert *UTF-16 from/to UTF-8* but none advise what to do if I have both. I'm trying to insert an email body text that has UTF-16 and UTF-8 characters, using PHP, into SQL Server 2008 table column (UTF-8).

I use `iconv()` to convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8 but as I said it is not enough because it doesn't handle UTF-8:

```
$email->description_html = iconv("UTF-16","UTF-8//TRANSLIT",$that->getMessageText(
                                 $msgNo, 'HTML', $structure, $fullHeader,$clean_email)); 
$email->description      = iconv("UTF-16","UTF-8//TRANSLIT",$that->getMessageText(
                                 $msgNo, 'PLAIN', $structure, $fullHeader,$clean_email));
```

I tried this for both UTF-16 and UTF-8 but it doesn't work, gives a database error:

`can't convert UTF-16 to UTF-8`

```
$email->description_html= iconv('','UTF-8',$that->getMessageText(
                                $msgNo, 'HTML', $structure, $fullHeader,$clean_email));
```

I don't know what else to do , please help.

Comment: There shouldn't be such a thing as "having both UTF-16 and UTF-8" in one text string. If this is the case, the string is broken. There must be an indicator stating which encoding was used, and this encoding only. This indicator must be trusted for converting characters into another encoding. If it doesn't work: Blame the source for incorrectly stating an encoding that wasn't true.

Comment: Thank you Sven, i have two ecodings in the same email in this scenario: Email written in Hebrew characters(UTF-8) that is scanned with Antivirus program that adds an emails extention text to it that it is verifaied - that email extetention (or call it attachment ,only it is not exactly an attachment...) is in UTF-16 (just like an NDR - non-delivery-report extention that added to the email text automatically). when i try to insert to the database (UTF-8) i get an error that the string is UTF-16. when i handle it as UTF-16, i can uknown characters where there was UTF-8.

Comment: Then your Antivirus program is simply broken. It should never add text with a different encoding to an email body part.

Comment: Thank you Sven and nwellnhof, you were both right , there wasn't UTF-16 with UTF-8 and the Antivirus did return UTF-8. Please post your comments as answers so i can mark as "answer" thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be such a thing as "having both UTF-16 and UTF-8" in one text string. If this is the case, the string is broken. There must be an indicator stating which encoding was used, and this encoding only. This indicator must be trusted for converting characters into another encoding. If it doesn't work: Blame the source for incorrectly stating an encoding that wasn't true.

As for email: It might be possible to have a multipart mail that has two (read: more than one) different parts with two different multipart headers, both of them stating different encoding. Dealing with this must be done by applying the rules for parsing multipart mails, i.e. you cannot treat the whole mail as a single string, but must separate these parts first - and then you have a perfectly valid single encoding case for each part. :)

Comment: The term "multipart mail" is the term i was looking for in the first place. THIS IS EXACTLY THE CASE I HAVE!. i just didn't know it was called multipart so i couldn't google it. thank you!